# How to make a transitive verb from an intransitive verb

Tags: causatives, transitivity

For example consider the *sleep* which is an intransitive verb, what is the verb for making one to sleep?

Is there any rule or transformation to make such verb using the intransitive verb?

Comment: There is no "rule". In the case of ***to sleep*** there's no "derived" transitive form that means ***to cause someone to sleep***. In the case of ***to starve***, it's just the same verb *Jack starved to death because Jill didn't feed him. She starved him*. Same for many other verbs, such as *wash, shave, feed*, etc.

Comment: No, you'll have to use a causative construction (*I made him sleep*) or a paraphrase (see Victor Bazarov's answer below) instead.  The version in your question (*\*making one **to** sleep*) is ungrammatical; *make* is one of the few verbs that takes a bare infinitival clause as a complement, not a *to*-infinitival.

Comment: --although a reader is likely to encounter *made him to {VERB}" because it was grammatical in English a few centuries ago,

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is a formula that, when used, allows a simple conversion of an intransitive verb to a transitive one.

As far as "sleep" goes, only "lull" and "hypnotize" come to mind.  Still, neither of them has actually the meaning you seek, I think.  So, instead a compound verbs would be used, e.g. "put to sleep" or "lull to sleep".